# Smooth autorotation animation

Tags: ios

I'm implementing autorotation support in my app, which is mostly a subclassed UIScrollView that does a bunch of special stuff (first image). `layoutSubviews` is called on the main `UIView`, which in turn calls the scrollview's `layoutSubviews`. This resizes the content to the new orientation's bounds, as expected (second image). Then the rotation animation happens. As a result, the user sees ugly dead space around the view after they rotate the device but before the newly-resized content rotates to its final position.

My app is written such that its contents have implicit animations turned off, so the resizing done by `layoutSubviews` is instantaneous. (Otherwise, I believe anything that happened there would be animated along with the rotation.) The simplest thing from my perspective (and given the app's visual contents) is to resize for the new orientation, then stretch it to look like the old orientation, then animate an undo of that stretch while the view rotates into position. This isn't working: tweaks to the `UIScrollView`'s `transform` property screw up its internal concept of geometry, and its parent `UIView` seems to overwrite changes to its `transform` if I make them in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`. Any transform made in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or later is animated, so by then I already need to be undo-ing the stretch I made earlier:

```
willrotate start, main transform [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] (untouched)
willrotate end, main transform [4, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0] (trying to stretch it arbitrarily)
willlayout, main transform [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0] (my stretch was overwritten by rotation; animation block has already started)
didlayout, main transform [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]
willanim, main trasform [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]
didrotate, main transform [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Normal view ==> resized view before rotation (I want to stretch this to cover the black space)

[image: Normal portrait view] [image: After resize, before rotation]

How can I stretch the new content before the animation, and have it unstretched at the end?
Alternatively, should I be doing this an entirely different way? Animating the resizing of all elements isn't an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without doubt, there is one comprehensive and definitive source you should be consulting for this question: WWDC2012, session 240, "Polishing your interface rotations".

It details a number of tricks for smoothing rotation animations.

The main one that occurs to me might be relevant to you is to call `setShouldRasterize` in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, configure your desired animation in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and then turn off `shouldRasterize` in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In my particular case, all I needed was:
`- (UIView *)rotatingHeaderView {
    return myScrollView;
}`
While a tad hacky (it's intended for a header), this overridable `UIViewController` method takes care of the stretching and fading for me entirely. Built-in code asks the `UIScrollView` for its appearance in before/after states and makes a nice transition for free.